# Read data from csv (pandas)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, read-data

I have two tables:

| reference_id | exclusiveness |
| --- | --- |
| 0047465 | luxury |
| 0165797 | luxury |
| 0013286 | selective |
| BB010 | selective |

| ticket-reference_id | product-reference_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2017010105521000016V | 47465 |
| 2017010105521000090V | 165797 |
| 2017010105521000111V | 13286 |
| 2017010105521000111V | BB010 |

For both tables i have used the code:

```
    pd.read_csv('df1.csv', sep = ';')
    pd.read_csv('df2.csv', sep = ';')
```

But in the second table in the column product_reference_id zeros are missed. The values from the column product_reference_id and reference_id have to be the same. So that i could join both tables.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  It *looks* as if you read one column as string, the other as integer, but you haven't given us enough context.

Comment: I have converted these columns to string values. What i need is to have the same values in column product-reference_id as in the column reference_id from the first table. But i dont know why excel load this column without zeros.

Comment: We don't know, either, since you haven't completed your MRE.  Please do so; then we can give a definitive repair.

Comment: Where is excel loading the data from? Is it an export from the dataframe itself (`df.to_excel`)? Does pandas show the right data types for the columns (`df.dtypes`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the CSVs themselves have the leading 0s? Can you paste in the first rows of each that correspond to the rows in your dataframe tables?

Assuming that the CSVs themselves both have the 0s, then you just have to read those columns in as strings. Since it looks like both cols in both CSVs are string-y, then you can read them in like this:

`pd.read_csv('df1.csv', dtype=str, sep=';')`

`pd.read_csv('df2.csv', dtype=str, sep=';')`

If you wanted to read some columns in as other datatypes, you can use a dict for dtype with the individual columns and types. See [the pandas docs for read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for info.

Comment: Chris thanks a lot!